# How to place an image above another image with making the underside image relative

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to have an icon from Front Awesome appear on top of an image I have on my page.  I have tried a few ways but can't seem to make it work.  Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="UserProfilePage"> 
    <a href="/fans/{{$fan->url_tag}}"><img src="{{$fan->image}}" width="195" height="195" style="z-index: 1;"></a>

    <a href="#" class="upload-photo"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x" style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; margin:0 auto"></i></a>

//...other user data here

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

(container/clearfix comes from twitter-bootstrap 2.3.2)

```
.UserProfilePage {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 130px 0 0;
}

.UserProfilePage img {
    border-radius: 130px;
    -moz-border-radius: 130px;
    -ms-border-radius: 130px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 130px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 130px;
}
```

The idea is to get the  object, somewhere hovering above the image above it.  However, when trying to do this, I am running into issues where it will only appear right outside of the image, etc...  Any ideas?  I tried making the top image "relative" but then it moved from where I wanted it.

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem. What element has to be relative? and which one can be absolute? Also your code is kinda messy, why do you have css setting styles and style attr setting style? why not set it all in the css like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F3MMR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try a line break:

`<br/>`

```
<a href="/fans/{{$fan->url_tag}}"><img src="{{$fan->image}}" width="195" height="195" style="z-index: 1;"><br/></a>
```

Comment: I don't think a line-break will achieve the desired effect of the icon appearing over the image.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want your icon to go on top of the profile picture.

Here is a fiddle containing something that would do that:

Without wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ym97/5/
With wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ym97/7/

I cleaned up your code to make it easier to read and understand. I also added a few things.

The main things to take note in my code are:

1. the icon `upload-photo` doesn't have the `z-index`, and `margin` rules anymore
2. the profile image doesn't have the `z-index` anymore, and the `width` and `height` are moved to the CSS.

The `upload-photo` has these rules now

```
.upload-photo {
    position: absolute; /* This is important */
    left: 81px; /* This could be anything */
    top: 83px; /* This could be anything */
}
```

To make things easier, I suggest wrapping the profile image and icon with a wrapper that's **positioned relative**.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working.  Strangely enough, even when I put the icon within this wrapper, it doesn't appear within the wrapper.  It appears in the upper left of the surrounding container (top left of the page)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of your new code to see if there's something missing?

Comment: This is what I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja4PC/3/

You can see that the camera appears outside of it.  This may have something to do with the bootstrap.css file, which has some css that has for:   img {
width: auto\9;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;

Comment: I was able to put it on top again. You were missing `position: relative` on the `UserProfileImageWrapper`. I also cleaned up the code and removed redundant rules. http://jsfiddle.net/Ja4PC/5/